# How is it possible to have docker images 41 yars old

Tags: docker, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Running  docker images on my workstation I see

```
pack.local/builder/qxoshxwcye                                             latest              41 years ago        782MB
paketobuildpacks/builder                                                  base                41 years ago        782MB
```

That some images are 41 years old. How is it possible?

Those images were pulled by doing  `gradlew bootBuildImage` (buildpack for Spring Boot application)